# Serial console enabled Performance is impacted. To disable, check bootloader

Tags: android

I recently created an Android emulator with Android version R.
It showing an Android system notification

**"Serial console enabled  Performance is impacted. To disable, check bootloader"**

Can someone explain, what this notification means?

[image],

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As because it's been more than 5 months since I posted this question and no valid answers so far, I'm sharing my findings.

1. What is a Serial Console?

The serial console is a connection over the RS-232 or serial port connection that allows a person access to a computer or network device console.
And a serial port is a serial communication interface through which information transfers in or out sequentially one bit at a time.

2. Why needed to enable serial console in emulator?

By enabling serial console in android emulator, developers can test serial port based applications in emulator.

3. Why is it related with bootloader?

To disable or enable serial console we need to change the android kernel configuration.
For know more about changing kernel configurations
Refer these links,
[http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:android:serial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210305041743/http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:android:serial)
https://gist.github.com/yan12125/78a9004acb1bed5faf2ffd442163e2ef

In conclusion,
With Serial console enabled in android emulator, the developer can use emulator to develop and test serial port based devices or hardware.
If you want to disable serial console, you need to download kernel source code google  provided https://gist.github.com/yan12125/78a9004acb1bed5faf2ffd442163e2ef

Then change the configuration , recompile and change kernel by running command

```
emulator -avd (avd_name) -kernel /path/to/goldfish/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -show-kernel
```

Documentation available in the above link...

Comment: Will it give a problem while developing?

Comment: No problems, everything will work like normal

Comment: Is it only me ? I find it too hard to follow the steps.

Comment: why isn't there a simple option to disable this?

Comment: Has anyone patched/compiled a kernel for Android 13 AVD with Serial Console turned off? This would be helpful to many who are looking and going on this topic. Many will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I was Creating App In Maui And After Reinstallation of emulator Started Getting This Issue.. Also Google Play service Error Issue to On running My App That Based on Google Maps.. so I Changed Emulator & Add Play store services + google Apis Both Changing Emulator Or Adding This Two Resolves This Issue for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I got similar issue on an Android 11 phone. It turned out that the usb cable had bad pin. After changing to a good usb cable. The problem went away.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30519050)

Comment: I think this poster meant to say: this message could mean you have a bad usb cable.  He glossed over that part and went directly to a solution.  Now whether that answer is a good answer or not is a different issue (kind of hard to test, right?).

Comment: @SMBiggs It's not about being a good or bad answer, it's not an answer to the problem at all. The question is clearly about an Android emulator and there simply isn't any real cable involved. It's a configuration problem, not a hardware issue.